# R raster extent (origin) has weird values

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r

I have a single band raster `r` with a large extent (several European countries). I assigned a CRS to it with:

```
crs(r) <- CRS('+init=EPSG:3035')
```

Properties of `r`:

`> r
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 20000, 40000, 8e+08  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 50, 50  (x, y)
extent     : 4e+06, 6e+06, 2e+06, 3e+06  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +init=EPSG:3035 +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : ~pathToRaster/r.tif 
names      : The_Raster`

The **extent** numbers are weird. I was expecting numbers (northing/easting?).
Why is there e.g. 4e+06 instead of a number?

`> extent(r)
class      : Extent 
xmin       : 4e+06 
xmax       : 6e+06 
ymin       : 2e+06 
ymax       : 3e+06`

4e+06 means 4*10 to the power of -6 ?? I am confused.

I am asking this because some further raster analysis do not work and I thought this might be the reason. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
xmin       : 4e+06 
xmax       : 6e+06 
ymin       : 2e+06 
ymax       : 3e+06
```

This notation is "e" for "exponential" notation. "4e+06" means "4 x 1,000,000" - a 4 times a 1 with 6 zeroes.

Your map is from 4000000 to 6000000 across, and these are (I think, in epsg:3035) metres. So your area is 2000000 metres across, which is 2000km.